# How to check the subclasses of an abstract class from the IDE

Tags: flutter, dart, ide

During coding, the hint shows us what type the property takes, for example:
[image]

This makes coding faster, but what if property takes subclasses of the  abstract class given in the hint, example:
[image]

How to check from the IDE (VS Code) what subclasses can be used?

Comment: Subclasses inherit the features of the superclass. This means you should be able to use all subclasses of the classes given in the hint.

Comment: because of the way some classes are structured, you can't always get the implementation or subclasses in the hint. You have to search manually or there might be an ide plugin out there that helps with auto-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best way that I use it is:

Using Android Studio (In VScode I think there is no way to do this since it is text editor not an IDE)

Hold ctrl (command on MAC), and click on the Class(Widget), which will take you to where the widget is defined.

then, near line numbers, you can find this icon shown in the image below, when click on it you will be able to see all available sub-classes.
[image]